# import data from MATLAB to c

Tags: c, matlab, matrix, import

Is there a simple way to import a *.mat file (or other MATLAB data file types), contains several / one complex matrix and save it to a c matrices?

thanks.

Comment: I found this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/read-and-write-matlab-mat-files-in-c-c-and-fortran.html, and this: http://matio.sourceforge.net/. You could also save the matlab data to a normal text file and read it in via the usual c fileIO idioms

Comment: Have you done a search at all?  Simply Googling "Converting Matlab to C/C++" produces About 334,000 results ( in 0.24 seconds)

Comment: Try this: http://bit.ly/1qzaUsz  ... [or direct link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5909/Exporting-Importing-Data-To-From-MATLAB) ...